# Unable to stop ActiveMQ(5.15.8) with OpenJDK

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, java-11, messagebroker

Getting the below Error while stopping ActiveMQ with OpenJDK. I can not enable JMX for security reasons.

Error

> Connecting to JMX URL:
>
> service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi INFO: Broker not
> available at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi.

While checking the AbstractJmxCommand class(Apache ActiveMQ open source code), I have found(line no 150) that it is using tools.jar(jdk/lib) but tools.jar is not available in open JDK.

Comment: From JDK 9 onwards, **tools.jar** is removed. Hope you get the same issue when using 9

Comment: I agree with your point that is only my question, How can we resolve this in open JDK or after jDK8 @Ramesh Subramanian.

Comment: I have tried the same version with open jdk 10 , there is no such exception. Can you provide some more details ?